# Hide overflow of inline element

Tags: html, css, ellipsis

How can the following be achieved (purely in CSS)?

- In a block of fixed width:
- display text, and an other character/image (✤) after it.
- However, when text is too long, hide its overflow,
- **while** still displaying the character/image (✤) after it.

Visually:

[image]

It should not:

- wrap the text
- grow the block
- hide the character/image (✤)
- always display the character at right

*Markup* (but feel free to suggest using other markup if that helps):

```
<div class=outer>
  <span class=copy>Text abc def ghi jkl mno pqr stu</span>
  <span class=symbol>✤</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Using flexbox’ grow and shrinking properties it _might_ be possible ...

Comment: @CBroe I hope so... Using a simple `flex: 1` or similar for the text on left, it wraps into multiple lines. Using `white-space: nowrap` it pushes the ✤ character out of the block...

Comment: Your text element need a width and you can use https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow the icon/image can be a different element altogether. You should really show your attempt, as your question stands now, it shows no research or attempted code and might get closed

Comment: You haven't given us any markup to work with. You won't be able to do this in pure CSS if all you have is a single element with that text and the icon as its only text content with no way of distinguishing the two.

Comment: @Huangism I was trying to avoid having to calculate the `max-width` for the text, but if there's no cleaner way..

Comment: @BoltClock Mark-up is flexible, I'm open to whatever works really

Comment: @Peter V: Fair enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using *positioning* - you can notice that when the text is short, the symbol will stay to the right end:

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding 10px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow:hidden;
  width: 100px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  position: relative;
}

div:after {
  content: '✤';
  position: absolute;
  right:0;
}
```

```html
<div>well, some text here</div>
<div>text here</div>
```

Here is a solution using `flexbox` where I got it working fully:

```css
div {
border: 1px solid red;
  padding 10px;
  width: 100px;
  display: flex;
}

div span {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow:hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

div:after {
  content: '✤';
  padding-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div><span>well, some text here</span></div>
<br/>
<div><span>text here</span></div>
```

Comment: That display: inline-block has no effect in either of your examples.

Comment: Awesome, the `:after` is key. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With the idea that your block has a fixed width, I'd just display the extra character/image with a `position: absolute;` as per:

**Extra char as Pseudo-Element**

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  padding-right: 25px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 150px;
}

span {
  position:relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 20px;
  max-width: 100%; /* or 120px or whatever you want */
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

span:after {
  content: '★';
  position: absolute;
  top: -2px;
  right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>text text text</span>
</div>
```

Declared the extra icon as a pseudo-element.

https://jsfiddle.net/6stc9hf0/1/

---

**Different approach** still considering declared static widths

```css
div {
   position: relative;
   display: inline-block;
   padding: 5px;
   padding-right: 25px;
   border: 2px solid black;
   width: 150px;
 }

.text {
  position:relative;
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: calc(100% - 20px);
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.icon {
  position: relative;
  top: -2px;
  right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="text">text text text text</span>
  <span class="icon">★</span>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6stc9hf0/2/